# In quantum experiments are we measuring the quantum state of a system or are we measuring the effect of the measurement on the quantum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

At the macro classical world, measurements in experiments when done correctly interfere very little with the state of the system under investigation.

As an example a digital ohmmeter with very high input resistance (10 MΩ or larger) measures very precise an external ohmic resistor component.

However, as we scale down in size entering the quantum world our measurements become much more disruptive to the system. I think this is called the *[Measurement Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem)* in quantum mechanics.

The more microscale we want to probe the quantum world the larger energies we have to use and the more intrusive and disruptive our quantum measurements become.

Things go even worse due to the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) which is regarded to be an intrinsic characteristic of the quantum world.

My question is two fold, what are today the most successful techniques in high-energy physics to tackle the measurement problem and how we are certain that these two phenomena the *Measurement Problem* in quantum mechanics and the *Uncertainty* are not correlated together phenomena?

Comment: That's not the "measurement problem". As the intro to the Wikipedia article you link says, the measurement problem is about how *deterministic time evolution* can produce the *probabilistic* outcomes of quantum measurements. That we "disrupt" the system being measured is an inevitable consequence of the probabilistic outcomes of measurements, not some experimental limitation you could "tackle" - I don't really understand what you're asking. (and also quantum phenomena are *not* intrinsically linked to size, like you seem to think, but that's a different can of worms (cf. Schrödinger's cat)).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I believe it is: " measurement problem is the problem of how, or whether, wave function collapse occurs." WP. It is the same as asking if the collapse is caused by the measurement altering the native quantum state. Ultimately asking if our quantum reality is product of our interaction?

Answer (score 1):

> In quantum experiments are we measuring the quantum state of a system or are we measuring the effect of the measurement on the quantum state?

I'd say both. Physics is holistic. Theory determines what you can measure and how to interpret the results and measurements determine, which theory is correct. All parts need to work together in unison.

From the theory and previous experiences with your measuring apparatus and methods, given the quantum state of the system you are about to measure, you know how your experiment is supposed to influence it. From the result, you can then infer information about the original quantum state. If you are doing your experiments and everything works well within established theory and knowledge you have, you are measuring quantum states, because you already know what effects your experiment has. If something is wrong, you are possibly measuring new effects that your experimental setup has that you do not know about yet.

Comment: By saying that prior to the measurement your system is in superposition of all possible states described by a wave probability function you actually admit that you do not know what the initial native quantum state of the system is? Correct me if I'm wrong. So the only specific state you will ever know is the measured state after the collapse of the wave function. possible caused by the measurement. In classical physics however you are pretty sure that native undisturbed state  and measured state are the same.

Comment: @Markoul11 Indeed, but you do get information about the original state. I edited the answer